# why OnActivated and OnResuming are not firing

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone, xamarin.winphone

I have an application where I have to run a piece of code when the application comes from the background to the foreground.

I can do it in three places(App.xaml.cs)

> 1. OnLaunched
> 2. OnActivated
> 3. OnResuming

I had a breakpoint in all three places, but I am not seeing it get hit in OnActivated and OnResuming.

Basically, if I long press on back button it'll bring me all the opened applications I can choose one to bring it to forward.

But I am not getting the breakpoint hit.

Comment: Stupid question, but are you in release mode? :D Do you use Cordova?

Comment: Is this Xamarin? Xamarin.Forms Application have OnStart/OnSleep/OnResume events.

Comment: this is xamarin native

Comment: Xamarin native does not have Windows / WP / UWP part.

Comment: does the form get the event instead of the app?